# Proper way to rig up eventemitters for communication between a parent and object instances?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, eventemitter

New to EventEmitter and ES6 classes, and I'm trying to grok the proper rigging. I have a "main" that instantiates an EventEmitter. In "main" I instantiate objects that I want to be able to listen for events emitted by "main"'s event emitter. I can pass a reference to main's EventEmitter to each object's constructor, but since the object's class is defined in a separate module file I think that it doesn't know that the ref is of type EventEmitter so within object's class I can't define an "on" listener on the ref to main's EventEmitter:

Main:

```
const listeningclassinstance = new ListeningClass(maineventemitter);
```

Submodule Class:

```
export default class ListeningClass {
  constructor(maineventemitter) {
    this.maineventemitter = maineventemitter;
  }
  maineventemitter.on("emittedevent", () => { // Visual Studio Code complains
    onemittedevent();
  });

  onemittedevent() {
    console.log("ListeningClass onemittedevent")
  }
  // ListeningClass
}
```

Comment: This looks like Angular

Comment: I think you have a syntax error. You cannot put arbitrary code inside of ES6 class blocks. Try moving the event binding to inside of the constructor function. You will also need to call the method like `this.onemittedevent()`

Comment: Thanks @djfdev that did the trick, sweet! Now to figure out how to pass events the other way ...

Comment: Jamie, I've looked at Angular a little but right now I'm focusing on ES6 and React. Point taken though about frameworks providing their own rigging ;-)

Comment: "*I think that it doesn't know that the ref is of type EventEmitter*" - that doesn't matter, you're not using TypeScript, right?

Comment: Hi Bergi, nope no TypeScript. This is an interesting puzzle for me since I am using Webpack's dynamic import for loading in a module named EventEmitter3. One thing I'm wondering is where/when ListeningClass should get EventEmitter3 ... pass it into ListeningClass's constructor or have the ListeningClass module import EE3 itself ... seems a better pattern to have ListeningClass import it.

Comment: Oh, to clarify yeah I was able to assign .on() within ListeningClass's constructor, worked great.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I rigged up, it's working although I know there's fancier getter/setter syntax in ES6. Also I'm passing in the EE3 class definition to the submodule's class after a single async call to load the EE3 module ... there might be a better way to handle that ...

Main:

```
// webpack dynamic import of EventEmitter3 here, setting a ref to EE3's class def
// the following Main code is actually within the dynamic import's promise then()

const listeningclassinstance = new ListeningClass(ee3class ,maineventemitter);
const listeningclassinstanceeventemitter = listeningclassinstance.getlisteningclasseventemitter();
listeningclassinstanceeventemitter.on("emittedeventfromlisteningclassinstance", () => {
    console.log("main can hear event emitted from listeningclassinstance");
  });
```

Submodule Class:

```
export default class ListeningClass {
  constructor(ee3class,maineventemitter) {
    this.maineventemitter = maineventemitter;
    this.maineventemitter.on(
      "emittedeventfrommain",
      this.onemittedeventfrommain.bind(this);
    this.eventemitter = new ee3class();  
  }

  onemittedeventfrommain() {
    console.log("ListeningClass emittedeventfrommain");
    this.eventemitter.emit("emittedeventfromlisteningclassinstance");
  }

getlisteningclasseventemitter() {
    return this.eventemitter;
}

  // ListeningClass
}
```